# VB.NET - Passing expression to be used within a function

Tags: vb.net, lambda, parameters, delegates

Part of my program consists of a series of steps that either complete, or time out after a certain interval. Test conditions vary widely. How do I write a single function to encapsulate all possibilities?

To do that I'd ideally need to pass the necessary condition to the function to be evaluated *within* the function, rather than to be evaluated as a parameter and then passed to the function.

This is what I would ideally want (greatly simplified):

```
Private Function TestCondition(<CONDITION>) as Boolean 
  ' Returns True if <CONDITION> fulfilled within 10 seconds
  Dim sw as New Diagnostics.StopWatch
  sw.Start()
  While sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 10000
    If <CONDITION> Return True
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
  End While
  sw.Stop()
  Return False
End Function
```

Function should work with any expression that returns a boolean value:

```
TestCondition(x=5)
TestCondition(System.IO.File.Exists("myfile")
```

Obviously, the above doesn't work as the *results* of specified conditions are passed to the function, rather than the conditions themselves.

Based on other reading, I can likely accomplish this by:

- Restructuring my code
- Using delegates
- Using lambda expressions

but I still do not see exactly how.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a lambda to the function which can be continually reevaluated.

```vb
Private Function TestCondition(predicate As Func(Of Boolean)) As Boolean
    Dim sw As New Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    While sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 10000
        If predicate() Then Return True
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    End While
    sw.Stop()
    Return False
End Function
```

```
Dim result = TestCondition(Function() File.Exists("myfile"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!!! Looking up lambda functions and "Func" keyword led me down quite a rabbit hole. I learned a lot. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

**Basically** the same as what djv said,

```
''' <summary>
''' waits for a condition for a number of seconds
''' </summary>
''' <param name="PredicateFunc">Function() conditional check )</param>
''' <param name="WaitForTMInSecs">seconds to wait</param>
''' <returns>boolean</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Function TestCondition(PredicateFunc As Func(Of Boolean),
                                Optional WaitForTMInSecs As Integer = 10) As Boolean
    Dim sw As Diagnostics.Stopwatch = Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew
    Dim _wait As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(WaitForTMInSecs)
    Dim rv As Boolean = PredicateFunc()
    Do While Not rv AndAlso sw.Elapsed <= _wait
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        rv = PredicateFunc()
    Loop
    Return rv
End Function
```

Tests,

```
    Dim result As Boolean
    result = TestCondition(Function() String.Equals("foo", "bar"), 2)
    result = TestCondition(Function() String.Equals("foo", "foo"), 2)
    result = TestCondition(Function() IO.File.Exists("myfile"), 2)
```

Comment: Elegant - thank you!